# C# Math conversions for pixels and frames

Tags: c#, user-interface

So I'm currently working on a c# tool where I need to calculate where the user clicks in the timeline and then get that current number within the range. The end result always should be an 'Integer' since this is based on frames.

[image]

Is this the correct way for writing the code to do this? I was not sure if there was a simpler way of writing it. All the 'Float' tags seem a bit much. How do i then just convert it to a Integer at the end? It seems a bit inaccurate...

```
        int ctrlX = e.X; // cursors X pos relative to control
        float perct = ((float)e.X / (float)this.Width); // control pixel width
        float normalizedWidth = this.maxValue - this.minValue;
        float val = this.minValue + (perct * normalizedWidth);
        label1.Text = val.ToString();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct?" It's only inaccurate if the user clicks in the middle and gets 120 instead of something close to the expected 150.

Comment: Me putting all the 'Float' tags correct? I wasn't sure if there was a simpler way of doing this math.

Comment: If it works, simpler is irrelevant.  You're not going to incur significant memory costs with this code, and the performance should already be instantaneous from the user's viewpoint.  Declare success, and get on with life.

Comment: Yeah. Your code is correct. You need that float conversion because you are calculating percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
label1.Text = ((int)val).ToString();
```

If you need it to round up or down, use `Math.Ceiling` or `Math.Floor` first!

Or simplify the whole thing to:

```
var result = this.MinValue + (int)( ( e.X / (double)this.Width ) * ( this.maxValue - this.minValue );
label1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Also note that you might get x values outside the control (seeing how it keeps mouse capture while the mouse is down), so you might want to care for that. (edit: if you allow the user to drag the value, that is)

Comment: Thank you Chris very much. I was looking for something like this. I'm not super familiar with c# so any alternate ways of doing things is helpful. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. The key here is that you only need to cast the divisor to a float/double to force it to do floating point arithmetic, it'll take care of the dividend itself.

Comment: i didn't know that. I was just looking that stuff up. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, floating point arithmetic is very unlikely to be a problem here. However you can use integer division to achieve this if you really want - note that this will round down:

```
int normalizedWidth = this.maxValue - this.minValue;
int val = this.minValue + (normalizedWidth * e.X) / this.Width;
```

However you do need to be sure that `normalizedWidth * e.X` won't overflow a 32-bit `int`.